# Django project deployed to Google App Engine is 3X as large in GCloud as it is locally

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I have a personal Django project that takes up 105.2 MB locally. Having deployed it to Google App Engine using [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine), I got the following error:

`Exceeded hard memory limit of 384 MiB with 435 MiB after servicing 0 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.`

I changed the instance to F4 which has more memory than the default, and that fixed it. I'm curious why the app needs another 330MB of memory though.

Comment: Because there are more things running in the instance in addition to your program like monitoring services, the runtime environment itself, etc. In your computer there are additional processes that make your app run, not only the app itself.

Comment: So even though the app engine is a serverless service, it still charges for the memory required for the computing environment overhead?